# declaring sigaction as a pointer type of value type

Tags: c, signals

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.0 20110419 (Red Hat 4.6.0-5)
```

I was just using sigaction and I was getting a stack dump when I was assigning the signal hanlder function to the sa_handler.

This is what I did using a pointer type:

```
struct sigaction *new_act = NULL;

new_act->sa_handler = signal_handler; /* This line produces the stack dump */

sigaction(SIGINT, new_act, NULL);
```

This is what I did using a value type:

```
struct sigaction new_act;

new_act.sa_handler = signal_handler; /* No problem here */

sigaction(SIGINT, &new_act, NULL);
```

What is the difference with using a value type of pointer type?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct sigaction *new_act = NULL;
```

This only creates a variable of type *pointer to* `struct sigaction`. It doesn't create a `struct sigaction` at all. No memory is allocated for that struct's fields, just enough to store the address of such a struct.

If you want to use a pointer, you'll need to allocate memory for the struct yourself using `malloc` for example:

```
struct sigaction *new_act = malloc(sizeof(struct sigaction));
```

and remember to `free` it when it's no longer being used.

The second version of your code correctly creates an object of type `struct sigaction`, so you can interact with it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake here is a really common misconception among programmers new to pointers. If I'm not mistaken, you've created a variable with pointer type based on the fact that the `sigaction` function takes a pointer argument. But the whole point of the argument is to *point to something*, namely the structure containing the signal handling information. When passing arguments to functions, you only need an *expression* whose type is compatible with the function argument type, not necessarily a variable of that type. For example, some beginners may tend to write:

```
struct sigaction new_act;
struct sigaction *new_act_ptr = &new_act;
/* ... fill in new_act here ... */
sigaction(SIGINT, new_act_ptr, NULL);
```

But the pointer variable here is completely useless. The expression `&new_act` by itself already has the right type, so you can just do:

```
struct sigaction new_act;
/* ... fill in new_act here ... */
sigaction(SIGINT, &new_act, NULL);
```